# Display videoframe and RenderTargetBitmap position

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to crop an image from webcam and display right next to the camera preview.

Cropping an image should be carried with 3 considerations.

1. Output of cropped image should be in form of `VideoFrame`
2. The above output, `VideoFrame`, needs to be displayed (on XAML)
3. The target crop image is in the middle of original image

I found `RenderTargetBitmap` would help me to get an cropped image.

But still I have no idea how to display `VideoFrame` (without saving an image), set the position where to crop.

I got stuck below...

```
    public async Task<VideoFrame> CroppingImage(Grid grid)
    {
        RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();

        await renderBitmap.RenderAsync(grid);
        var buffer = await renderBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
        var softwareBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer(buffer, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, renderBitmap.PixelWidth, renderBitmap.PixelHeight, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore);

        buffer = null;
        renderBitmap = null;

        VideoFrame vf = VideoFrame.CreateWithSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);
        await CropAndDisplayInputImageAsync(vf);

        return cropped_vf;
    }


    private async Task CropAndDisplayInputImageAsync(VideoFrame inputVideoFrame)
    {
        //some cropping algorithm here
        //i have a rectangle on a canvas(camera preview is on CaptureElement)
        //I know the left top position and width and height but no idea how to use
    }
```

Any help?

***This is what i found and done :)***

(assume that there is a videoframe which name is croppedface)

```
        croppedFace = new VideoFrame(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, (int)width, (int)height, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore);

        await inputVideoFrame.CopyToAsync(croppedFace, cropBounds, null);

        SoftwareBitmap asdf = croppedFace.SoftwareBitmap;
        asdf = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(asdf, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore);
        var qwer = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
        await qwer.SetBitmapAsync(asdf);
        CroppedFaceImage.Source = qwer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But still I have no idea how to display VideoFrame(without saving an image), set the position where to crop.

If you want to show the frame on the xaml, you need to convert the frame to a displayable format and rendering it to the screen. Please check the [FrameRender](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraFrames/cs/FrameRenderer.cs#L123) class in the official **Camera frames sample**. It has a `ConvertToDisplayableImage` method that should be what you want.

Then, you could show it in Image control. After that, you could use [Image.Clip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.clip#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_Clip) to set the position where you want to crop.